# How do I get my python function to read data from another .py file

Tags: python, function, spyder

Note: I have simplified my problem below. Also, I am using Spyder.

I have saved a function called testFunc in a .py file. This function gives you the mean value of a subset of a list of numbers.

This is the function, FYI:

```
def testFunc(X):
    subSet = List[0:X]
    Output = sum(subSet)/len(subSet)
    return Output
```

In my master .py file, I load the data:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I then pull the testFunc function from a separate folder:

```
%run '/Users/mak/Dropbox/Python/My functions/getScore.py'
```

Then I try to run my data through my function:

```
testFunc(2)
```

However I get a message

```
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

When I run the function and define the List in the same .py file, I do not have this problem. But I do not want to do this as my code is very long.

The other thing I can do is define the List as part of the function. But I am wary of doing this as my actual dataset (List) is massive and pulling it everytime I want to run this function seems less than elegant.

Is there a third way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import` the list before you can use it:

master.py:

```
x_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

test.py:

```
from master import x_lst

def testFunc(X):
    subSet = x_lst[0:X]
    Output = sum(subSet)/len(subSet)
    return Output
```